# jquery delay fadein with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to get a `fadeIn()` `delay` to work.

I've read loads about interval and it's not helping, also timeout but it's not currently helping.

I'm calling the below function `onclick` and just want it to cycle with 3 seconds delay then if called again to start from `si-1` (first `div`)

The function is looping but delay isn't in sync with the `setTimeout` call so after the first loop it starts skipping `div`s until it only show the last `div` and flickers.

Any pointers?

Here is the code:

```
function runAnimation() {
    hiAni(); // hides all si- div's
    $('.si-1').delay(0).fadeIn();
    $('.si-2').delay(3000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-3').delay(6000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-4').delay(9000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-5').delay(12000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-6').delay(15000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-7').delay(18000).fadeIn();

    t = setTimeout(function(){runAnimation()},21000);
}
```

It runs fine bar if you multi click! 
**Here is my js fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/FvNYy/4/

Comment: Do you want to wait for each one to complete before the next happens?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/LQvH2/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
function runAnimation() {
    hiAni(); // hides all si- div's
    $('.si-1').delay(0).fadeIn();
    $('.si-2').delay(3000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-3').delay(6000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-4').delay(9000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-5').delay(12000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-6').delay(15000).fadeIn();
    $('.si-7').delay(18000).fadeIn(function(){
        // Using fadeIn complete callback to run the animation
        t = setTimeout(function(){runAnimation()},100);
    });
}
```

Or maybe something like this (triggering next fadeIn on each element):

```
function runAnimation() {
    hiAni(); // hides all si- div's
    $('.si-1').fadeIn(function(){
        $('.si-2').fadeIn(function(){
            $('.si-3').fadeIn(function(){
                $('.si-4').fadeIn(function(){
                    $('.si-5').fadeIn(function(){
                        $('.si-6').fadeIn(function(){
                            $('.si-7').fadeIn(function(){
                                t = setTimeout(function(){runAnimation()},100);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work, each fadeIn runs on completion of the previous:

```
function runAnimation() {

    hiAni(); // hides all si- div's

    $('.si-1').fadeIn(3000, function(){
        $('.si-2').fadeIn(3000, function(){
            $('.si-3').fadeIn(3000, function(){
                $('.si-4').fadeIn(3000, function(){
                    $('.si-5').fadeIn(3000, function(){
                        $('.si-6').fadeIn(3000, function(){
                            $('.si-7').fadeIn(3000, function(){
                                t = setTimeout(function(){runAnimation()},21000);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work? I added the hiAni function to enable the click to reset the animation. Feel free to adjust to fit your needs.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3gSQ/11/)

```
function hiAni() {
    $('.main').children().stop().removeAttr('style');
}
function runAnimation() {
    $('.main').children().each(function() {
        var t = $(this).index() * 3000;
        $(this).delay(t).fadeIn();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    runAnimation();
    $('.main').children().on('click', function() {
        hiAni();
        setTimeout(runAnimation, 3000);
    });
});
```